# Normalize integer types to float range

Tags: c++, template, integer, floating-point, casting

I wrote two template functions to take an integer type and output a `float` in the given range. One function takes signed integers and the other takes unsigned integers.

The functions are used to normalize audio PCM data into a range that an encoder is expecting, such as [0.0f, 1.0f]. The source audio data can come in many forms (signed, unsigned, 1 byte, 2 bytes, etc) so I thought template functions would be ideal for this.

The caller has the responsibility of calling the function with an appropriately sized type containing the sample to normalize (e.g. `int16_t`). The functions use a lookup-table to determine the max/min values the type can contain based on the size of the integer type.

### util.cc

```
#include <stdint.h>

const uintmax_t MAX_VALUE_PER_BYTES_UNSIGNED[] = {
    0,
    uintmax_t(UINT8_MAX),
    uintmax_t(UINT16_MAX),
    uintmax_t(UINT16_MAX) + uintmax_t(UINT8_MAX),
    uintmax_t(UINT32_MAX),
    uintmax_t(UINT32_MAX) + uintmax_t(UINT8_MAX),
    uintmax_t(UINT32_MAX) + uintmax_t(UINT16_MAX),
    uintmax_t(UINT32_MAX) + uintmax_t(UINT16_MAX) + uintmax_t(UINT8_MAX),
    uintmax_t(UINT64_MAX)
};

const intmax_t MAX_VALUE_PER_BYTES_SIGNED[] = {
    0,
    intmax_t(INT8_MAX),
    intmax_t(INT16_MAX),
    intmax_t(INT16_MAX) + intmax_t(INT8_MAX),
    intmax_t(INT32_MAX),
    intmax_t(INT32_MAX) + intmax_t(INT8_MAX),
    intmax_t(INT32_MAX) + intmax_t(INT16_MAX),
    intmax_t(INT32_MAX) + intmax_t(INT16_MAX) + intmax_t(INT8_MAX),
    intmax_t(INT64_MAX)
};

const intmax_t MIN_VALUE_PER_BYTES_SIGNED[] = {
    0,
    intmax_t(INT8_MIN),
    intmax_t(INT16_MIN),
    intmax_t(INT16_MIN) + intmax_t(INT8_MIN),
    intmax_t(INT32_MIN),
    intmax_t(INT32_MIN) + intmax_t(INT8_MIN),
    intmax_t(INT32_MIN) + intmax_t(INT16_MIN),
    intmax_t(INT32_MIN) + intmax_t(INT16_MIN) + intmax_t(INT8_MIN),
    intmax_t(INT64_MIN)
};
```

### util.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

extern const uintmax_t MAX_VALUE_PER_BYTES_UNSIGNED[];
extern const intmax_t MAX_VALUE_PER_BYTES_SIGNED[];
extern const intmax_t MIN_VALUE_PER_BYTES_SIGNED[];

template <typename T>
float normalizeToRangeFloatSigned(T num, float rangeMin, float rangeMax) {
    float f = 0.0f;

    if (!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer) {
        return f;
    }

    const float rangeDiff = rangeMax - rangeMin;
    if (!rangeDiff || rangeDiff < 0.0f) {
        return f;
    }

    uintmax_t uintRangeMax = MAX_VALUE_PER_BYTES_UNSIGNED[sizeof(T)];

    const intmax_t tRangeMin = MIN_VALUE_PER_BYTES_SIGNED[sizeof(T)];
    const intmax_t tRangeMax = MAX_VALUE_PER_BYTES_SIGNED[sizeof(T)];
    const intmax_t tRangeMinAbs = std::abs(tRangeMin);
    float percent = 0.0f;

    if (num < 0) {
        if (num == tRangeMin) {
            percent = 0.0f;
        } else {
            percent = (tRangeMinAbs - T{-1} * num) / float(uintRangeMax);
        }
    } else if (!num) {
        percent = 0.5f;
    } else {
        if (num == tRangeMax) {
            percent = 1.0f;
        } else {
            percent = (num + tRangeMinAbs) / float(uintRangeMax);
        }
    }

    f = (percent) * rangeDiff + rangeMin;

    return f;
}

template <typename T>
float normalizeToRangeFloatUnsigned(T num, float rangeMin, float rangeMax) {
    float f = 0.0f;

    if (!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer) {
        return f;
    }

    const float rangeDiff = rangeMax - rangeMin;
    if (!rangeDiff || rangeDiff < 0.0f) {
        return f;
    }

    uintmax_t uintRangeMax = MAX_VALUE_PER_BYTES_UNSIGNED[sizeof(T)];
    f = (num / float(uintRangeMax)) * rangeDiff + rangeMin;

    return f;
}
```

I don't have much experience with templates so any feedback is welcome. Also, any improvements to the functions time-efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<limits>` already provides a set of limits on values that can be stored in the various types. It's also a template, so it's easy to invoke on a template parameter. As a quick demo of that particular part of things:

```
template <class T>
void showminmax(T) { 
    std::cout << "min: " << std::numeric_limits<T>::min() << 
               "\nmax: " << std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}

int main() { 
     std::cout << "int\n";
     showminmax(1);

     std::cout << "\nunsigned long long\n";
     showminmax(1ULL);
}
```

I believe the code to normalize the number to the range [0..1] can be simplified quite a bit as well, to something on this order:

```
template <class T>
float normalize(T t) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Input must be integral");
    float min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    float max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    float range = max - min;

    return (t - min) / range;
}
```

This should work for either signed or unsigned types. Here's a quick bit of demo code to exercise it, and show the results:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "char(min):   " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<char>::min()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "char (1/4):  " << normalize(char(std::numeric_limits<char>::min() >> 1)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "char (0):    " << normalize('\0') << "\n";
    std::cout << "char (3/4):  " << normalize(char(std::numeric_limits<char>::max() >> 1)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "char (max):  " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<char>::max()) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "int(min):   " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<int>::min()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "int (1/4):  " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<int>::min() >> 1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "int (0):    " << normalize(0) << "\n";
    std::cout << "int (3/4):  " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<int>::max() >> 1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "int (max):  " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "uint (0):   " << normalize(0U) << "\n";
    std::cout << "uint (1/4): " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() / 4) << "\n";
    std::cout << "uint (mid): " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() / 2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "uint (max): " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()) << "\n\n";


    std::cout << "ULL (0):   " << normalize(0ULL) << "\n";
    std::cout << "ULL (1/4): " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() / 4) << "\n";
    std::cout << "ULL (mid):  " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() / 2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "ULL (max):  " << normalize(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()) << "\n";
}
```

Note that twos complement is asymmetric, so the values produced are technically just a tiny bit off (well, off from what you might expect, anyway). This will normally be lost in the rounding for any type with more than ~24 input bits, but if the input type is smaller than that (e.g., most implementations of `char` and `short`) a signed value of `0` won't give precisely 0 as the result (unless you have a machine with something like signed-magnitude or ones complement int, anyway).

Comment: Your version for the [0,1] case should speed up encoding a bit without all the conditionals. I didn't realize that `<limits>` had those ... limits, though it seems obvious now. Also I believe my version suffers the same issue with not being exact for signed values, but for 16 bit values at least they look pretty close.

Comment: @Chase: It's not really that they aren't exact. It's what you typically expect that isn't quite exact. For example, we expect `0` to be the middle of the range of signed numbers--but it's really not; there's one more negative than positive number, so 0 isn't *quite* exactly in the middle. With a 16-bit number, the deviation is very small though: about 1 part in 32767, or roughly .003 percent. For 8-bit numbers, it's much larger (relatively speaking).

Comment: Thankfully I haven't come across many signed 8-bit PCM audio samples (pulseaudio doesn't even accept plain 8-bit signed samples). I'll have to look into handling that case in the event it does pop up.